# При наборе текста в инпут, текст выходит за пределы инпута с левой стороны

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hook

Я увеличиваю ширину инпута в зависимоcти от его value. Так выходит, что когда идет набор текста, левая сторона немного уходит за границы инпута. Уже не в первый раз сталкиваюсь с этой проблемой. Подскажите, пожалуйста в чем дело? и как это исправить?
Мой код тут: `codesandbox`- https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-feistel-iqwqg?file=/src/App.js

Так выглядит проблема при наборе текста:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
const Input = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const spanEl = useRef(5);

  const changeHandler = (event) => {
    setInput(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <span className="hide" ref={spanEl}>
        {input}
      </span>
      <input
        className="input"
        type="text"
        value={input}
        onChange={changeHandler}
        style={{ width: spanEl.current.offsetWidth + "px" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

```css
.container,
.input,
.hide {
  font: inherit;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  min-height: 40px;
}
.input {
  outline: none;
  width: 2px;
}
.hide {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: а как вы хотели бы? чтобы уходила вправо?

Comment: ну так вы учтите в ширине родительского контейнера паддинги и бордеры и будет вам счастье

Comment: Хочу чтобы никуда не уходило. @МихаилРебров пробовал для родительского класса .container устанавливать все значения box-sizing. Все также. Напишите пожалуйста пример

Answer (score 0):

Это размеры вашего поля ввода 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы устанавливаете размеры текстового поля по размеру введенного текста,
но вы не учитываете то, что в реальности из области для ввода текста вычитаются:

- 2 пикселя внутреннего отступа слева
- 2 пикселя внутреннего отступа справа

**Итого:** область для ввода в реальности получается на 4 пикселя меньше, чем нужно, отчего ваш текст и съедается.

Просто учтите данные размеры и прибавьте их к ширине текстового поля.

```js
const Input = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const spanEl = useRef(5);

  const changeHandler = (event) => {
    setInput(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <span className="hide" ref={spanEl}>
        {input}
      </span>
      <input
        className="input"
        type="text"
        value={input}
        onChange={changeHandler}
        style={{ width: spanEl.current.offsetWidth + 4 + "px" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

```css
.container,
.input,
.hide {
  font: inherit;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  min-height: 40px;
}
.input {
  outline: none;
  width: 2px;
}
.hide {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

И ваш текст будет помещаться в область для ввода

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Либо уберите внутренние отступы у текстового поля, чтобы они не мешали вашим вычислениям:

```css
.input {
  padding: 0px; /* <-- */
  outline: none;
  width: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Попробовал оба варианта. Безуспешно :( https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-feistel-iqwqg?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Dmitriy, да, я когда проверял - просто обновил скрипт и отображение обновилось. И кое-что я в таком случае упустил, а именно то, что стиль инпута обновляется ДО ТОГО как обновился спан. Соответственно changeHandler "отстает" ровно на одно событие. Сейчас я подумаю над этим

Answer (score 0):

Это можно решить с помощью useEffect, подписавшись на изменения инпута.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import React from "react";
const defaultWidth = 5;

const Input = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [spanWidth, setSpanWidth] = useState(defaultWidth);
  const spanEl = useRef(null);

  const changeHandler = (event) => {
    setInput(event.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
   // Смотрим, если инпут имеет больше 1 символа, тогда делать рассчёт.
    if (input.length > 0) {
      setSpanWidth(spanEl.current.offsetWidth);
    }
  }, [input]);
   
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <span className="hide" ref={spanEl}>
        {input}
      </span>
      <input
        className="input"
        type="text"
        value={input}
        onChange={changeHandler}
        style={{ width: spanWidth + "px" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

[Пример codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-sound-1ehbq0?file=/src/App.js)